# In dbt macro function, I tried to use ref("table_name").identifier but got parsing error

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

This is a macro function that I made

```
{#
    Macro: load_with_schema_info

    Description:
        - Generates the model YAML configuration for a list of provided tables.
        - Constructs a WITH clause for each table.
        - This is for giving information to the ai

    Args:
        table_names (list): A list of tuples. Each tuple contains:
            1. Alias for the table.
            2. Model reference.

    Returns:
        String: A SQL WITH clause followed by model YAML configuration in comments.

    Example:
        {{ load_with_schema_info([("alias1", ref("model_name1")), ("alias2", ref("model_name2"))]) }}
#}

{%- macro load_with_schema_info(table_names) -%}
   {%- set ref_table_names = [] -%}
    {%- for table_tup in table_names -%}
        {%- set ref_table_name = table_tup[1].identifier -%}
        {%- set _ = ref_table_names.append(ref_table_name) -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
      /*
    {%- set model_description = codegen.generate_model_yaml(ref_table_names) -%}
    {{ model_description | replace("\n\n", "\n") }}
    */
    with
        {%- for table in table_names %}
            {{ table[0] }} as ({{ select_star(table[1]) }}),
        {%- endfor -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

but when I try to use it, I got an error:
Error while parsing node: inline_query
Sql_Operation 'sql_operation.<project_name>.inline_query' (from remote system.sql) depends on a node named 'inline_query' which was not found

I made this macro to use with gpt to tell information about previous models.
expected output is:

```
/*
version: 2

models:
  - name: <table_name>
    description: ""
    columns:
      - name: column1
        description: ""
      - name: column2
        description: ""
...
*/
with
table_alias as (select column1, column2 from {{ref("table_name")}}),
...
```

select_star macro is working well (it is basically `select {{dbt_util.star(...)}} from {{ref(...)}}`)

if I change the model reference (tuple[1]) to text, and use ref later, it worked. but I want to use ref("") as parameter because dbt cloud auto-complete model name.

what would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think dbt must be passing relations given as macro args (or vars for that matter) as strings, and not as their original Relation...

I had a similar problem trying to use a relation's identifier when the ref was given as a project var.

As a work around, I've used the following macro which makes it work as expected (the returned object being a (real) Relation)

```
{% macro parse_ref(ref) %}
    {% set splitted = ref.rsplit(".") %}
    {% set table = splitted[-1] %}
    {% if splitted|length == 3 %}
        {% set database = splitted[-3] %}
        {% set schema = splitted[-2] %}
    {% elif splitted|length == 2 %}
        {% set database = None %}
        {% set schema = splitted[-2] %}
    {% elif splitted|length == 1 %}
        {% set database = None %}
        {% set schema = None %}
    {% else %}
        {%- do exceptions.raise_compiler_error("Parsing not possible for ref: " + ref) -%}
    {% endif %}
    {% set rel = api.Relation.create(database, schema, table) %}
    {{ return(rel) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Usage in your example would be: `{%- set ref_table_name = parse_ref(table_tup[1]).identifier -%}`

Clearly this is not very satisfying and should really be handled natively!! But in the meantime, it works...